# How to send commands to STDIN of bash process from a socket?

Tags: c, bash, sockets, unix

I am trying to get /bin/sh using a malloc vulnerability called House of Spirit. The problem that I am facing is that after getting the shell in the server side I want to send commands to it from the launched socket. It's important to note that I cannot use a reverse shell as the shellcode that I am using to gain a shell must be less than 64 bytes.

The good thing is that I can personalize the server code as much as I want, it is just for testing.

My server handles the socket connection like this:

```
void func(int sockfd) 
{ 
    //REDIRECTING STDOUT TO SOCKED
    dup2(sockfd, STDOUT_FILENO);
    dup2(sockfd, STDERR_FILENO);
    int pipe_fds[1];
    pipe(pipe_fds);
    char buff[MAX]; 
    int n; 
    int pid = fork();
    //HERE FORK TO LAUNCH A BASH
    if (pid == 0) {
        //REDIRECTION OF BASH STDIN TO PIPE_FDS
        dup2(pipe_fds[1], STDIN_FILENO);
        char numberArgBuffer[20];
        sprintf (numberArgBuffer, "%d", sockfd);
        char * argv[] = { "/bin/sh", NULL, NULL, NULL };
        execve( argv[0], NULL, NULL );
    } else if (pid == -1) {
            printf("Error creating child\n"); 
    }   
    for (;;) { 
        bzero(buff, MAX); 
  
        printf("Reading...\n"); 
        read(sockfd, buff, sizeof(buff)); 
        n = 0;

        // copy server message in the buffer 
        while ((buff[n++] = getchar()) != '\n') 
            ; 
      
        // HERE IT SHOULD SEND COMMANDS TO THE LAUNCHED BASH 
        write(pipe_fds[1], buff, sizeof(buff)); 
      
        // if msg contains "Exit" then server exit and chat ended. 
        if (strncmp("exit", buff, 4) == 0) { 
            printf("Server Exit...\n"); 
            break; 
        } 

        bzero(buff, MAX); 
        waitpid(-1, NULL, 0);   
    } 
}
```

If I use it without redirecting the STDIN and I type the commands on the server side I can see their output, nevertheless, when I try to redirect the standard input of the bash to my created socket so I can send commands to it (like the previous code) does not work. Any idea of what I am doing wrong? Any possible solution using pipes?

The only thing I can not modify are the following lines:

```
char * argv[] = { "/bin/sh", NULL, NULL, NULL };
execve( argv[0], NULL, NULL );
```

Comment: Connecting the write end of a pipe to standard input isn't going to work well — `dup2(pipe_fds[1], STDIN_FILENO);` needs either `0` in place of `1` or `STDOUT_FILENO` in place of `STDIN_FILENO`.

Comment: You should have code after `execve()` to handle the case where the `exec` fails.  Normally, that'll exit; it probably reports an error to stderr too.  Giving no arguments to the shell is cruel and unusual punishment (`execve( argv[0], NULL, NULL );`) — you created `argv` so you should probably be using `execve(argv[0], argv, NULL);` though if you're not providing a new environment, you should probably just use `execv()` instead.  Unless you really intend to run the shell with no environment variables at all (no HOME, no PATH, no …), but that's not usually recommended.

Comment: You might ask your teacher why the `execve()` line is so weird.  And the `argv[]` array is wasting two pointers – not a big deal, but why bother if the code isn't going to use it anyway.